# How to disable v-if compilation caching when condition is truthy again?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have following scenario: I use the v-if to dynamically compile and insert the partial html into DOM.
Everytime, v-if condition goes to true, the contents of the partial will change. Unfortunately, it seems the next compilation behaves strange: "the changed part NOT compiled".
I have read the document http://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show
it says:
"
v-if is also lazy: if the condition is false on initial render, it will not do anything - partial compilation won’t start until the condition becomes true for the first time (and the compilation is subsequently cached).
"
My question is: Is there a method to disable the cache( force v-if to compile everytime **whenever** condition is truthy)?

I have created a little complex fiddle to demonstrate that concept: on the second time v-if condition goes truthy, v-if will not compile changed contents, please check following :
https://jsfiddle.net/matiascx/d1ea22nc/6/

The expected behavior is: when changing the content of v-if wrapped content, the v-if will compile it and insert it to dom every time v-if condition is truthy. Unfortunately, it only work the first time condition becomes true. It never works after the first time. It should be the v-if compilation cache problem. How can i disable that cache and make it work as I expected?

```
.
```

Comment: It's a issue in Vue.js look [here](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/77) for more infos

Comment: I have no idea, i am currently using v1.0.26, information on that issue is for v0.10,0.11, but i am not sure that is relative to newest vue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a preview component with a template and add the content there.

HTML

```
  <preview v-if="displayme">{{{content}}}</preview>
  <template id="preview">
    <div>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </template>
```

If that isn't possible because of components. Here is an extended discussion on the compile function https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/254.

But notice this [comment](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/254#issuecomment-121279001) where it is suggested that you use repeats to create new components on the fly. See if you can use `v-for` to create the list of components and this will get you around the HTML compilation issue.

Comment: {{{ content }}} will not work, because content has some customized component which will not be compiled

Comment: I added some more to my answer they may help.

Comment: thanks. currently, i have switched to vuejs2.0 and use the render function to fix this. Hope can help with other people